# Nexus 4 is not detected in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Windows 7 with the latest version of Android Studio (v 2.3.3).
I googled a lot and applied the possible solutions that I found, but still no luck.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zl4GV.png

Comment: Which possible solutions did you find? And why are they not working for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi try with this universal driver. try after install it

http://adbdriver.com/downloads/

Comment: Thank U its really helpful .. I resolved problem by installing it...:)

Comment: It saved me. Worked like a charm !

Answer (score 0):

Install the USB Driver that is available in the SDK Manager.

Check this for more information

https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html